# UIRefreshControl bug when entering foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uirefreshcontrol

I've noticed a little bug (but really annoying) when I use `UIRefreshControl` in my View Controller.  When the application returns from the background the `UIRefreshControl` is already loaded and it looks like this:

[image]
[image]

As you can see I use a custom navigation controller which hides like in the Facebook app (`AMScrollingNavBar`). When I reload data in `UITableView` everything comes back to normal and this bug shows only after returning from the background.

This is the code which I use to initialize `UIRefreshControl` in `viewDidLoad`:

```
// Initializing generic refresh control
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(collectData) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.tableView addSubview:self.refreshControl];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a known bug in iOS7. You can see it reproduce in Apple's mail app. I can confirm it has not been fixed as of <strike>iOS7.1 beta 5</strike> <strike>iOS8.0 beta 3</strike> iOS 10.0.1.

First, open a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com/
My radar number is `rdar://14586451`, which is a duplicate of `rdar://14493713` (still open).

A proposed fix is to register for `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` notifications in your view controller and call `[self.refreshControl.superview sendSubviewToBack:self.refreshControl];` to somewhat remedy the issue by having the refresh control appear behind your table content.

I see in the second screenshot that the refresh control shows under your cell. This is likely because you have set a clear color as your cell's background. Set it to white.

Comment: It's a shame that it's still not animating like it should. Your answer helped me to, at least, hide this awful view! I will reconcile using custom pull-to-refresh again in that case!

Comment: There are a lot of other bugs with UIRefreshControl. I think I made around 10 bug reports for this class.

Comment: April 2016, iOS 9.2 - still freezes.

Answer (score 7):

I found one workaround for a variation of this bug. It might potentially help with yours, too. In my app, switching to another tab and going back to the tab with the refresh control broke it - the control didn't animate any more while dragging.

Instead of setting up UIRefreshControl in viewDidLoad, I set it up in viewDidAppear, and then always remove it in viewDidDisappear. This way it's always initialised fresh and doesn't get confused.

As in the previous answer to this question, i've requested UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification so that the refresh control can be fixed also when the user jumps back in the app.

```
@implementation MYViewController {
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    /* Pull down to refresh. iOS bug: If we add this in viewDidLoad and let it
     * stay there for the lifetime of the view, the control will misbehave
     * after going to another view/tab and coming back (will not animate nicely
     * on drag).
     */
    [self setupRefreshControl];

    /* We'll want to be notified for didBecomeActive, to do the pull-down-to-refresh workaround when resuming. */
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(setupRefreshControl)
            name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)setupRefeshControl
{
    if (refreshControl)
        [refreshControl removeFromSuperview];

    refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshPull:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [scrollView addSubview:refreshControl];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    [refreshControl removeFromSuperview];
    refreshControl = nil;

    /* We don't need notification for becoming active any more */
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
        name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
      object:nil];
}
```

Slightly suboptimal, but works.

Comment: Encountered another variation on this for iOS9/XCode 7.2: On a UINavigationController-managed, subclassed UIViewController containing a UICollectionView, pushing/popping to the navigation stack while also calling setNavigationBarHidden(_:animated:) causes the refresh control to appear immediately after the content offset of the collection view changes by 1pt. Additionally, the refresh control is in a fully opaque state and does not animate. But having a function similar to yours in viewDidAppear resolves this.

Answer (score 5):

This bug seems to occur when making a modal presentation over the table view controller as well as when the app returns from the background.

The simplest fix is to call `endRefreshing()` in `viewWillAppear(_:)` and upon receiving the notification `UIApplicationWillEnterForeground`.  You need to do both because `viewWillAppear(_:)` is not called when the app returns from the background.

The effect of calling `endRefreshing()` on an instance of UIRefreshControl appears to be to return the control to the correct location in the view hierarchy and ensure that it continues to animate correctly on subsequent refreshes.

Remember to check that your refresh control is, in fact, not refreshing.

In Swift:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    endRefreshing()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
        selector: #selector(endRefreshing),
        name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground,
        object: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self,
        name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground,
        object: nil)
}

func endRefreshing(_ notification: Notification? = nil) {
    if refreshControl?.isRefreshing == false {
        refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
    }
}
```

Tested in Xcode 7.0 targeting iOS 8.0 with a UITableViewController configured in the storyboard.

Comment: Hi, I tried this but my app crashes when it returns from the background. It can't find the selector. "unrecognized selector sent to instance". Only when I return from the background, otherwise it works fine :/

Comment: Didn't help, but I removed the notificationCenter calls instead, and it seems to work. Haven't experienced the bug yet either and that was 3 days ago. Hopefully it works :)

Comment: "Modal window" - You are not using the term "window" correctly here.